# What wrong with the function?

Tags: python, string

I'm new to coding and python is my first language.
I'm trying to make a function which removes all the special characters, but 
I can't seem to find the problem whenever I use this:

```
def Remover(sentence):
 special_chars = (',', '.', '!',';', ':', '\"','','|')
 for char in special_chars:
   for words in sentence:
     if words == char:
       replaced_sentence = sentence.replace(words, "")
       print replaced_sentence
```

When I enter
`hi,`
I get this

```
hi
```

Which is what I want, but when I enter `hi, hi,`
I get this:

```
hi hi
hi hi
```

Why? I should get `hi hi` but why 4 times?
[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zciNr.png)

Comment: Hint: notice how many times you're looping over.

Comment: Because, you loop over the sentence, and each time you replace something you also print.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you print your new `sentence` inside of the `for` loop. This means, for every time you encounter a special character, you `print` the new sentence.

You should wait until you have finished looping to `print` (so it only happens once).

However, you are also misusing the `replace` function. I would suggest you change your code to something like this instead:

```
def Remover(sentence):
    special_chars = (',', '.', '!',';', ':', '\"','','|')

    for special_char in special_chars:
        sentence = sentence.replace(special_char, '')

    print(sentence)
```

This would be the proper way to use the `replace` function, instead of looping over your string and then doing `replace`. The `replace` function replaces all instances of a character in a string, so you only need to use it once.

Comment: You appear to have beat me, in any case +1 because this is the correct solution.

Comment: You need to adding the result of the `.replace` method call or else this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the replacement every time `words == char` is true. So if there are two `,` in the sentence, you'll print the replacement twice.

You don't need to loop over the sentence. `sentence.replace()` will replace all the occurrences of the character, so you only need to call it once for each character you want to replace.

You also need to assign the replacement back to the `sentence` variable, so that you'll get all the replacements in one place. Otherwise, each time you're starting from the same original string, replacing a different character, and the final result will just be from the last set of replacements.

```
def Remover(sentence):
    special_chars = (',', '.', '!',';', ':', '\"','','|')
    for char in special_chars:
        sentence = sentence.replace(char, "")
    print sentence
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have indicated, you're currently printing every time you do a replace (not just when you're done editing the string). You'll print exactly as many times as you replace; for example, `hi, hi,` has 2 replace operations. `hi,,,, hi` has 4. Thus, you'll replace 2 times followed by 4 times. (I'd encourage you to try that at this point to convince yourself that that's the case).

Try this:

```
def Remover(sentence):
 special_chars = (',', '.', '!',';', ':', '\"','','|')
 for char in special_chars:
   for words in sentence:
     if words == char:
       replaced_sentence = sentence.replace(words, "")
 print replaced_sentence
```

Simply print at the end once you're editing the string (instead of editing every time).